# CSS height percentage filling from bottom to top

Tags: html, css, height, percentage

well i have a container div and in it a transparent image with border only, take a look:
[image]

and i want dynamically later to change the container height percentage so it will look like the figure is being filled. With the dislike it works great, as the height percentage grows the color is filled from top to bottom. is it possible in the "like" case to fill from bottom to top somehow?

those are the css relevant values:

```
.like{
    width:150px;
    height:55%;
    margin-right:50px;
    float:right;
    border-radius:10px;
    background-color:#159C89;
}

.Dislike{
    width:150px;
    height:45%;
    background-color:#ff0000;
    margin-left:50px;
    float:left;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

Comment: Could you paste your html and css into something like jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Pretty sure this won't work. if these are transparent images the background would affect the outside of the 'hands' as well.

Comment: ok: http://jsfiddle.net/6d54J/

Comment: the pictures are only have a draw (black border), it's transparent inside and has white background outside.

Answer (score 4):

This example may help you  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/kbjohnson90/pen/DcAnC)

```
<div class="battery yellow" data-max="60" data-fill="35">
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="battery yellow" data-max="18" data-fill="9">
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="battery green" data-max="5" data-fill="3">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using JS.
if the like percentage is 55% , the remaining empty space will be 45%.
so you just set that 45% as margin-top to '.like' class!! using JS.
As you are applying margin-top it will move down, which appears to be filling from bottom!!

Comment: you should not write css property as margin-top:45%; directly!!
apply using JS dynamically using clientHeight property!!
get the clientHeight of ".likeoicsholder" and calculate 45% height of it and apply the value as margin-top to the ".like".
you must do whole thing on document.ready.